# Why can I not put a certain URL in a Chrome Extension JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to code a Chrome Extension, but I am getting an error of something relating to the URL.

Code:

```
{
  "name": "Axqua's Themes for V3rmillion",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://v3rmillion.net]",
      "js":  ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Error:

```
Required value 'content_scripts[0].matches' is missing or invalid.
```

However, when I put `<all_urls>`, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to do `https://*.v3rmillion.net/*` instead of just the link.

[Chrome Dev Docs for Ref](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/#declaratively)